# Return a list in MVC causes an error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to return a list of schedule in education system. I have a **schedule** model in my Project with this property:

```
public partial class Schedule
{
    public Schedule()
    {
        this.ClassTimes = new HashSet<ClassTime>();
        this.Scores = new HashSet<Score>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }
    public int LessonId { get; set; }
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public int DegreeId { get; set; }
    public int FacultyId { get; set; }
    public int SemesterId { get; set; }
    public int MajorId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateOfExame { get; set; }
    public string Capacity { get; set; }
    public string locationOfExame { get; set; }

    public virtual Class Class { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClassTime> ClassTimes { get; set; }
    public virtual Degree Degree { get; set; }
    public virtual Faculty Faculty { get; set; }
    public virtual Lesson Lesson { get; set; }
    public virtual Major Major { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Score> Scores { get; set; }
    public virtual Semester Semester { get; set; }
    public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}
```

So in this model I save the `id` of my entity for example major, teacher, lesson, etc. So I need to return a list of my schedules. So I have to convert the `id` of my entity to name of that entity. So I design a schedule controller in my MVC project like this:

```
private readonly ScheduleRepositor obj = new ScheduleRepositor();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var list=new List<SchedulePresentation>();
    ClassRepository objclassrep=new ClassRepository();
    DegreeRepositor objdegreerep=new DegreeRepositor();
    FacultyRepositor objfactulyrep=new FacultyRepositor();
    LessonRepository objLessonRep=new LessonRepository();
    MajorRepository objmajorrep=new MajorRepository();
    SemesterRepositor objsemesterrep=new SemesterRepositor();
    TeacherRepositor objteacherrep=new TeacherRepositor();
    DateConverter objdateconverte = new DateConverter();
    List<Schedule> model = obj.GetLessonlist();
    foreach (var t in model)
    {
       SchedulePresentation objpres=new SchedulePresentation();
        objpres.Capacity = t.Capacity;
        objpres.DateOfExam = objdateconverte.ConvertToPersianToShow(t.DateOfExame);
        objpres.className = objclassrep.FindClassById(t.ClassId).ClassName;
        objpres.degreeName = objdegreerep.FindDegreeById(t.DegreeId).DegreeName;
        objpres.examLocation = t.locationOfExame;
        objpres.facultyName = objfactulyrep.FindFacultyById(t.FacultyId).FacultyName;
        objpres.lessonName = objLessonRep.FindLessonById(t.LessonId).LessonName;
        objpres.majorName = objmajorrep.FindMajorById(t.MajorId).MajorName;
        objpres.semesterName = objsemesterrep.FindSemesterById(t.SemesterId).SemesterName;
        objpres.teacherName = objteacherrep.FindTeacherById(t.TeacherId).Name + " " +
                              objteacherrep.FindTeacherById(t.TeacherId).LastName;
        list.Add(objpres);

    }

    return View(list);
}
```

So I just create a repository for each entity to return the name of my entity by **id**.

And I create a representation class for my schedule to convert the `id` to name of my entities like this:

```
public class SchedulePresentation
{
    public string teacherName { set; get; }
    public string lessonName { set; get; }
    public string className { set; get; }
    public string degreeName { set; get; }
    public string facultyName { set; get; }
    public string semesterName { set; get; }
    public string majorName { set; get; }
    public string DateOfExam { set; get; }
    public string Capacity { set; get; }
    public string examLocation { set; get; }
}
```

So I have two problems. I have 4 projects in my solution:

1. DomainClass
2. Model
3. Repository
4. MVC project

So

1. Is it a good method that I convert these Id to their name in the MVC layer, or it is better to make a Repository or create a model for this list of schedules?
2. In the last line when I want to return my list I got this error:

   The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EducationMVC.PresentationClass.SchedulePresentation]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DomainClasses.Schedule]'.

The view code of MVC :

```
@model IEnumerable<DomainClasses.Schedule>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TeacherId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LessonId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClassId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DegreeId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FacultyId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SemesterId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MajorId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateOfExame)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Capacity)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.locationOfExame)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TeacherId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LessonId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClassId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DegreeId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FacultyId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SemesterId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MajorId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateOfExame)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Capacity)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.locationOfExame)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: In your controller you create a list of `SchedulePresentation` object, which you pass to your view. Your view, probably (as you didn't post the code) has the declared model type of `@model IEnumerable<Schedule>`. Change it to `@model IEnumerable<SchedulePresentation>`.

Comment: Yes exactly so what should i do ?so can i make an empty view and pass this model to that ?after this i should handle the list by myself

Comment: You have two options: either change the model type from the controller (i.e. return a list of `Schedule` objects -- create/use a mapper) or change the model from the view. It really depends on what's best for your architecture and logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view probably has a strongly typed model like this

```
@model IEnumerable<DomainClasses.Schedule>
```

but you are returning a `List<SchedulePresentation>`.

One solution would be to change the model line to: `@model IEnumerable<SchedulePresentation>`.

Comment: So i changed it ,but the same error ,and my view could not find the model properties

Comment: Wait, is your problem solved or not? because you marked my answer as correct.

Comment: I changed it to @model IEnumerable<SchedulePresentation>.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question lies in the error message:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EducationMVC.PresentationClass.SchedulePresentation]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DomainClasses.Schedule]'.

It seems like the view corresponding to this method (by default the Index view of your controller) is expecting a model of type `IEnumerable<Schedule>`.

If you wish to send a `List<SchedulePresentation>`, change the model type in the view to `IEnumerable<SchedulePresentation>`.

**Hint**: In your view, one of the first lines should be of the form:

```
@model IEnumerable<DomainClasses.Schedule>
```

which you could change like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<EducationMVC.PresentationClass.SchedulePresentation>
```

Comment: So i changed it ,but the same error ,and my view could not find the model properties .

Comment: Make sure to also have the proper @using statements in your view. In this case I guess you need using EducationMVC;  and/or using EducationMVC.PresentationClass;

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the error reported by the compiler. You're passing to a view a model object of a certain type (`SchedulePresentation`), when the view expects a model object of type `Schedule`.

In particular, in the lines:

```
List<Schedule> model = obj.GetLessonlist();
foreach (var t in model)
{
    SchedulePresentation objpres=new SchedulePresentation();
    objpres.Capacity = t.Capacity;
    objpres.DateOfExam = objdateconverte.ConvertToPersianToShow(t.DateOfExame);
    objpres.className = objclassrep.FindClassById(t.ClassId).ClassName;
    objpres.degreeName = objdegreerep.FindDegreeById(t.DegreeId).DegreeName;
    objpres.examLocation = t.locationOfExame;
    objpres.facultyName = objfactulyrep.FindFacultyById(t.FacultyId).FacultyName;
    objpres.lessonName = objLessonRep.FindLessonById(t.LessonId).LessonName;
    objpres.majorName = objmajorrep.FindMajorById(t.MajorId).MajorName;
    objpres.semesterName = objsemesterrep.FindSemesterById(t.SemesterId).SemesterName;
    objpres.teacherName = objteacherrep.FindTeacherById(t.TeacherId).Name + " " +
                                  objteacherrep.FindTeacherById(t.TeacherId).LastName;
    list.Add(objpres);
}
```

you're creating a `List<Schedule>` but you add to it objects of type `SchedulePresentation`, when the model specified in your view expects the type `IEnumerable<DomainClasses.Schedule>`. For this reason, you have the error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EducationMVC.PresentationClass.SchedulePresentation]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DomainClasses.Schedule]'.

To solve the problem, change your model line to `@model IEnumerable<SchedulePresentation>`.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question, I'd say the MVC controller is the right place to extract the information from what the repository returns, and put it in a view model (your `SchedulePresentation` class). However, the code you posted will result in an aweful lot of database queries - for each item in your schedule, you'll end up with eight extra queries to get the related items. In a schedule with 20 items, that's an extra 160 database queries to get stuff you could probably have included.

You've tagged this `[entity-framework]`, so I'm going to assume that you're using it to get the `Schedule` items from your database. Instead of using the id's of the items, use the actual properties:

```
for (var t in model) {
    SchedulePresentation objpres=new SchedulePresentation();
    objpres.Capacity = t.Capacity;
    objpres.DateOfExam = objdateconverte.ConvertToPersianToShow(t.DateOfExame);

    objpres.className = t.Class.ClassName; // <- this works!
}
```

Now, doing just that will not save you any db queries - it will just clean up your code a little. Due to lazy loading, EF will still retrieve the relevant `Class` object from the db *when you ask to look at it*, rather than at the top. However, if you in your repository add an `Include` statement to your EF query, you'll start saving - then EF will include the related items in the original query, and they will already be fetched from the db. This will look something like the following:

```
var ctx = getYourEFContextSomehow(); // pseudocode, obviously...

var scheduleItems = ctx.Schedules.Include(s => s.Class); 
// Add more Include for other objects
```

There are other ways to turn off lazy loading for specific properties or entire objects as well - check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232

Comment: Yes it works .i just replaced the **finbyid** to the actual property that you said.thanks